# Partial match of application DisplayNames in Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, registry

I'm a PowerShell noob.  Sorry in advance.  I'm trying to write a quick script that will check a PC to see if a list of applications are installed.  I'm storing the list in an array, and comparing it to the DisplayName of apps in the Uninstall keys in the registry.

```
$Apps=@('Paint.net', 'Blender', 'SketchUp')

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  Where-Object {$Apps -Like $_.DisplayName} | 
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

This works, but only for exact matches.  "Blender" and "Paint.net" are listed in the output, but not SketchUp, because the full DisplayName is "SketchUp 2017".  How do I get this to match keywords regardless of the other text (version numbers) in the DisplayName?  I've tried wildcards around the $_.DisplayName property, but they either throw an error or don't return anything at all.  I'd rather not have to update the script every time Audacity's version clicks up a couple of notches.

This is probably something simple, like expanded properties or something, but it is beyond my grasp.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: A common powershell question but I can't find a good answer to link to. You can compare (a) against (m) - check one thing against the other.  You can compare (a,b,c,d) against (m)  - that has a standard behavior, if anything in (a,b,c,d) matches (m) then trigger one answer. But you're trying to compare (a,b,c,d) against (m,n,o,p) in one move and get one answer - you can't, what would the output be? You need two loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is make a Regular Expression out of your `$Apps` array, and use `-match` against that. You will need to escape your strings to account for any special characters, and join them with a pipe (which in RegEx is the `or` operator).

```
$Apps=@('Paint.net', 'Blender', 'SketchUp')
$AppsRegEx = ($Apps | ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match $AppsRegEx} | 
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

That should match keywords for you.